# expression to update column based on other column sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, expression

Here are my tables .. I have table 1 and table2

[image]

I want an expression in SQL to update the price of car in table 1 if it is = 0 .. by set the price of the car same as the another product which has the same integer on (`Table2.N`). .. and the same date (`Table1.Date`)

### FOR EXAMPLE ON the figure ..

I want the car price be the same as house price on april (`date`)
 (I chose house because car and house has same record on (`Table2.N`)

Comment: OK. And what stops you?

Comment: I couldn't find the right SQL expression .. !

Comment: Post your best effort so far.

Comment: UPDATE table1
SET price=(select price from table1 where .......)
WHERE price=0;

Comment: sorry ,I'm a beginner

Comment: What if `Table 1` had Tree with `N=2` and price `200`? How would you determine the price of a car in such situation.

Comment: its only take the price which is same (table2.n) and same ( table1.date) .. there will be only tow product of table 2 which has same number !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Price = t.Price  
FROM  
       (  
          SELECT Price, N
          FROM Table2
          WHERE Product-N != 'Car'
       ) t  
WHERE (Table1.Product-N = 'Car' AND Table1.Price = 0 AND Table1.N = t.N AND Table1.Date = t.Date)
```

Comment: and if i don't want to determine the  name of the pruduct which has price= 0

Comment: UPDATE Table1 SET Price = t.Price  
FROM  
       (  
          SELECT Price, N
          FROM Table2
          WHERE Product-N != Table1.Product-N
       ) t  
WHERE (Table1.Price = 0 AND Table1.N = t.N AND Table1.Date = t.Date)